# Do the Groovy every and any methods short-circuit?

Tags: groovy

Suppose the every or any method is being evaluated on a long list, and the value of the closure on the first element is enough to determine the final result (true for any, false for every).  Do these methods continue processing the rest of the elements of the list or do they immediately return?

```
def lst = [1,2,3,4]
//Do either of these functions evaluate the 2nd, 3rd and 4th element of lst?
boolean value1 = lst.any{element -> element == 1}
boolean value2 = lst.every {element -> element == 2}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`any()` and `every()` short-circuit and return as soon as possible.

You can see this in the source for [`any()`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_11/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L2475) and [`every()`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_11/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L2363). These methods each iterate over each object evaluating the closure and return if the condition is (for `any()`)/is not (for `every()`) met.